# Show two closed paths are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How to show that any closed path in $$\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$$ is  homotopic to a closed path with image in $S^1$?

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide some context as to what you already know.

Comment: This is just an exercise, and there is no more specific context. What I want to prove is for arbitary closed path in R^2 - {0,0}, there exists a closed path with image in S^1 , and two paths are homotopic.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{R}^2 - (0,0)$ and $S^1$ are homotopy equivalent, have you shown that already? If not, start there. Then use that homotopy equivalence.

Comment: For a path $\gamma(t)$, $H:(t,x)\mapsto (1-x)\gamma(t)+x\frac{\gamma(t)}{\Vert \gamma(t)\Vert}$ will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.